# Unable to add tags in GCP. Require compute.instances.createTagBinding permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, tags, editor, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to add tags to my instances and I only have the basic editor permissions, even for basic, they are quite a lot of them. Anyways, when I try to add tags it says: `Resouce: instance-1 compute.instances.createTagBinding`
I tried searching for the specific permissions in roles from my manager's account, in front of him but I wasn't able to find them. I searched them in My Project > IAM > Clicked on the pencil icon on the extreme right of my user. I could not find these specific permissions. There was nothing related to createTagBinding.

However, I was provided the Tag administrator permissions though but unfortunately those are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAM role `roles/editor` has limited compute engine tag permission:

- compute.instances.listEffectiveTags
- compute.instances.listTagBindings
- compute.instances.setTags

One of the roles that grant permissions to create tags is `roles/resourcemanager.tagUser`.

For more information regarding roles and permissions:

[Creating and managing tags](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing)